# Enable/disable antimalware extension on Azure Cloud Service classic via script

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-cloud-services, antimalware

We are using Cloud Service Classic (still - for now) as a deployment model for a number of our websites. While migration to something else is on the cards, it's not yet. We activated the antimalware extension via the Azure portal - and here's where the issues started.

Our CI/CD system completes builds nightly and deploys them to QA servers using API.  The deployment bit has worked fine and still is.  However this deployment creates hundreds of thousands of small files on the actual servers (nothing we can do about - this is part of the 3rd party platform being used).  As a result, the antimalware extension is scanning every file and the deployment takes hours to complete.  Without Antimalware the deployment takes about 1 hour.  With it enabled - close to 5 hours.

Based on how our deployments work, it's safe to disable the antimalware before the deployment, complete the deployment, then re-enable it again.  Yet, I can't find any way to do it from our CI scripts. The only reference I see are the powershell cmdlets `Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension` and `Remove-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension` - yet these have been removed from the Azure Powershell quite some time ago - and I can't find the version that still has it.

What other options are there? How can I disable/enable Antimalware extension on Cloud Service from a CI script?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right in that only `Set` and `Remove` actions are available with Microsoft Antimalware for Azure. Microsoft Antimalware is installed in a disabled state in the Cloud Services platform and requires an action by an Azure application to enable it. AFAIK, these cmdlets are available only in version `4.0.0` of the Azure Module as specified in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/set-azureserviceantimalwareextension?view=azuresmps-4.0.0).

I'd suggest to open an issue with the [Azure-Powershell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell) repo so our Team can take a look at this and understand your requirment better. Thanks for reaching out!